# When is the strong dual equal to the weak dual?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Consider $V$ a topological vector space, and $V'$ the dual (space of all continuous linear forms on $V$) and $V'_w$ the weak dual (space of all weakly-continuous linear forms on $V$).

Under what condition on $V$ do we have the equality : 
$$
V'=V'_w \ \   ?
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [Duality gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_gap)?

Comment: I'm not, but reading from your link, I don't see how this can answer my question. Maybe you can explain ?

Comment: Maybe I mix something,  but it seems for me that since the weak topology on $V$ is weaker than topology of $V$  then each weakly continuous map on $V$ is strongly continuous, so $V_w’\subset V’$. Conversely, weak topology on $W$ is defined as a strongest topology in which all linear forms are continuous, so $V’_w\supset V’$. Thus $V’_w=V’$, right?

Comment: I think you mean that it is defined as the weakest/coarsest topology, not the strongest.